# Need a solution to implement xmpp add friends in group chat and sending message to them in once in php

Tags: xmpp

I am Working on chat application from server side where one to one and group chat are the modules.

```
I am able to create the new room for the group chat.

But i am unable to invite the friends to that group using php code.

if somebody has sample code that would be great..

I write below code for sending invitation to user for that group but it is not working for sending invitation to user and it also not throw any kind of Exception.As above i have describe i am working on chat application in which i have to send invitation so that device side developer can used this invitation and call the web api for refreshing the list automatically.

<?php  

$url = "http://host:port/plugins/mucservice/message?servicename=conference";
$data = "
<message from='9879870000spalchat@canopus-pc(e.g.senderjid)' to='3698000000spalchat@canopus-pc(e.g.receiverjid)'>
   <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'>
     <invite from='yorkvillecommunityschoolspalchat@conference.canopus-pc(e.g.groupjid)'/>

   </x>
 </message>

";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, "9090");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password")));
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $code;
$res = curl_exec($ch);
//echo "code " . $code;
echo $res;
print_r($res);

curl_close($ch);
```

I  have done R&D for this and then i have find out it is done by muc service Plugin.

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Comment: If you can upload what code you have done so far, it will be easier to answer the question. If not, then it's more of a shot in the dark. (Unless someone happened to have done this exact thing).

Comment: yes i have uploaded the code